# How to add custom field in item's label printing?

Tags: netsuite

I am modifying item label Advanced PDF template to include custom field into item's label print. 
I have custom field "Price Including Tax", which have addition of price and tax,but it is not available in the list to include.
[image]
How can I add custom field in template?

I've tried to include custom field manually in html editor like:

```
${label.CustomFieldID}
```